# Does the LIBELAS depend on camera parameters?

Tags: c++, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

I want to use LIBELAS(Library for Efficient Large-scale Stereo Matching) to generate the disparity map. My stereo camera has 25 cm baseline and 12mm focal length. I cannot generate sufficient disparity map for my stereo images? Could you please guide me why the disparity map is noisy? Does ELAS library depend on camera parameters?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think this library LIBELAS caliculates disparity for each pixel between stereo image pairs. It does not depend on camera parameter.
So the reason why you can't generate clean disparity is too few feature on the image to find. Only expanding the image resolution is the way to solve this.

By the way, Depth is calculated by disparity, focus length and baseline as following.

```
depth = baseline * focus_length / disparity
```